# Convert object series to time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I'm having an issue analyzing data with a time column in my data frame (which I open from an excel file). The values in the specified column are like the following:

05:29:04, 05:36:52, 05:43:20, 05:50:39, 05:57:54

They suppose to represent "arrive and depart" time but in python, the column is recognized as an object and not a time series.

I'm not sure what should I do in order to convert the column to time series- I tried several functions such as `to_datetime` or `timestamp` but keep getting errors so I'm not sure I fully understand how to convert the column.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need convert values to [`timedelta`s](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5],
                   'col':['05:29:04', '05:36:52', '05:43:20', '05:50:39', '05:57:54']})

print (df)
   A  B       col
0  a  4  05:29:04
1  b  5  05:36:52
2  c  4  05:43:20
3  d  5  05:50:39
4  e  5  05:57:54

df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'])

print (df.dtypes)
A               object
B                int64
col    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

If convert it to datetimes, `year`s, `month`a and `day`s are added by default:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%H:%M:%S')
print (df)

   A  B                 col
0  a  4 1900-01-01 05:29:04
1  b  5 1900-01-01 05:36:52
2  c  4 1900-01-01 05:43:20
3  d  5 1900-01-01 05:50:39
4  e  5 1900-01-01 05:57:54
```